# Compare two data uri images php

Tags: php, html, jquery

I want to compare two data URI images. is there is any solution for that?

I have used below code but it's not working:

```php
$file1 = file_put_contents('file1.png', file_get_contents($data_before[$key]));
$file2 = file_put_contents('file2.png', file_get_contents($value));

$previousImageHash = md5_file('file1.png');
$currentImageHash  = md5_file('file2.png');

if ($previousImageHash != $currentImageHash)
{
    $description_note .= "<p><strong style='color:#000'>Signature</strong> was updated \n</p>";
}
```

it fails even i haven't made any change to the signature.

**The library i am using is signature pad.**

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare? Do you mean if they have exactly same data or something else?

Comment: Can you not just compare the two string values? `file_get_contents($data_before[$key]) != file_get_contents($value)`

Comment: Are you trying to compare two different signatures and see if they are similar within some kind of tolerance? Or comparing for exactly the same bytes? What is this library? Can you provide examples of images that should be compared equal? We need more to go on if byte equality isn't going to work.

Comment: @Phil it doesn't work with this library, it gives different data URI value for same signature.

Comment: @RobRuchte the library i am using is a javascript library with name signature pad. the images which are provided by this library are in data URI. i have used the solution provided over but none of themis working for me.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation for the library? There's nothing to go on here, and we're not going to go hunting for it.

Comment: @RobRuchte  https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad#signature-pad---

Comment: Per the documentation: "NOTE: This method does not populate internal data structure that represents drawn signature. Thus, after using #fromDataURL, #toData won't work properly." Is this the cause of your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use [md5_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php).

```php
$file1 = file_put_contents('file1.png', file_get_contents($data_before[$key]));
$file2 = file_put_contents('file2.png', file_get_contents($value));

$previousImageHash = md5_file('file1.png');
$currentImageHash  = md5_file('file2.png');

if ($previousImageHash != $currentImageHash)
{
    $description_note .= "<p><strong style='color:#000'>Signature</strong> was updated \n</p>";
}
```

Comment: Not working, @Rob i am using signature pad for signature which provides out put in data  URI even if i haven't made any changes the out of $previousImageHash and $currentImageHash   are 43e17c07b71b7d2e16f7c5a3963787a5 & 0c06322cd6f11da5e1f68048c45a4362
so our code fails with this condition

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that.